# Flutter WebViewX how to show a loader until the page loads

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to show a circular progress indicator while loading a web page using the WebViewX package.

I can't find any property in WebViewX that is onLoading or something similar.

I wan't the loader to show until the page loads then I want to dismiss it.

here's my code

```
WebViewX(
          initialContent: Provider.of<GoLootLooViewModel>(context,listen: false).finalURL,
          initialSourceType: SourceType.urlBypass,
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) => widget.webviewController = controller,
           height: double.infinity, width: double.infinity,

      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use html loader in initialContent with type .html
and give final url in webviewcontroller.loadContent('finalUrl');